# Java wildcard reference

Tags: java

Imagine I have a class wildcard class called Value to save a type of value that can be a String, an int, or a boolean.

```
public class Value<Type>{
   Type _value;

   public Value(Type value) {
       _value = value;
   }

   public Type getValue() {
       return _value;
   }

}
```

I will save a bunch of instances from this class in an array like this:

```
private ArrayList<Value<?>> _myValues = new ArrayList<Value<?>>();
```

After this I am going make something with the values that I stored. So how can I check for each Value instance in the ArrayList if it is an int, a String or a boolean and  then assign it to a variable? Something like:

```
//If it is it
int myNumber = someValueInstance.getValue();
```

Is something like this even possible to do?

Thank you.

Comment: What for? You see if you work out and tell us what you want to do with these values, there might be a better way. Assigning to a local variable is not an end-goal in itself.

Comment: @weston I am making a very simple interpreter than recognize function/operation that return only int, String or boolean

Comment: return them to what? What's next once you have the int/String or Bool?

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to do instead of using a primitive variable to store the contents of the ArrayList I would use Wrapper objects. You could get the certain values from the ArrayList and put it into the wrapper object.

But without knowing the type of the ArrayList of Values, I don't think it would be possible to determine it before you store it in a variable because you have to know what your storing before you store it. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

`Value<?>` is essentially equivalent to `Value<Object>`, so the return type of `getValue` would be `Object`. You could use `instanceof` to check if the value is an `Integer`, `String`, or `Boolean`.

```
Object val = someValueInstance.getValue();
if (val instaceof Integer) {
    int number = (Integer)val;
    //...
} else if (val instaceof String) {
    String string = (String)val;
    //...
} else if (val instaceof Boolean) {
    boolean bool = (Boolean)val;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realistically speaking, the only way to do this is with a bunch of `instanceof` checks, but this defeats the purpose of the generics, in my mind.

You have a list full of `Value<?>`, which means tacitly, ***I don't know what type is contained in these `Value` objects, but I want a list of them.***  The wildcard form is more convenient if you don't *care* about the type contained in your wrapper, since acting on the type is more complicated than it needs to be (lots and lots of `if` statements with `instanceof` - remember, this generic is ***unbound***).

If you know the types, then you should *declare* them in the collection you have; create as many collections as you need to act on.  This creates more overhead in the fact that now you have to do some work on inserting them into the right list, but it is simpler, more straightforward and more conventional to act on the value contained in the wrapper.

```
List<Type<String>> stringWrappers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Type<Integer>> integerWrappers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Type<Boolean>> booleanWrappers = new ArrayList<>();
```